# How to post array in swagger api

Tags: php, json, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have integrate swagger php api outr rest-api all service working fine but i am facing issue in post json array in api. this is not working can  you please help me.

Here my swagger api code

```
/**
 * @SWG\Post(path="/createbetsnap/get_all_game_data",
 *   tags={"Create Betsnaps Section"},
 *   summary="This function used to get selected tournament schedule date and other master data like size, prize structure and entry fee",
 *   description="",
 *   operationId="get_all_game_data",
 *   produces={"application/json"},
 *   consumes={"application/json"},
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="Login_Session_Key",
 *     in="header",
 *     description="The Login Session Key of logged in user.",
 *     required=true,
 *     type="string"
 *   ),
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="game_tournament",
 *     in="formData",
 *     description="The game tournament ids array field.",
 *     required=true,
 *     type="array",
 *     @SWG\Items(type="string")
 *   ),
 *   @SWG\Response(response=200, description="success message with data array"),
 *   @SWG\Response(response=500, description="Invalid username/password supplied")
 * )
 */
```

above complete code on swagger which i added before my api.

I want to post game_tournament field like

```
{"game_tournament":["18","8"]}
```

But from swagger-ui panel post in below format

```
game_tournament=8,18
```

can you please help me what wrong with my code, what i need to change.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

using e.g. Swagger Lume package for Laravel / Lumen, you can obtain what you are asking by:

```
 *     @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="game_tournament[]",
 *         in="query",
 *         description="The game tournament ids array field",
 *         required=true,
 *         @OA\Schema(type="array", @OA\Items(type="string")),
 *     ),
```

Answer (score 1):

To POST JSON data, you need to use an `in: body` parameter and specify the data type using `@SWG\Schema`:

```
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="game_tournament",
 *     in="body",
 *     description="The game tournament ids array field.",
 *     required=true,
 *     @SWG\Schema(
 *       type="array",
 *       @SWG\Items(type="string")
 *     )
 *   ),
```

Comment: but how post array with body tag, can you please provide some example sample code. i have added in="body" but it require schema field.

Comment: @Helen Am receiving  "game_tournament" field as null in my API.Girish are you able to receive the posted array in api?

Comment: I am having a almost same problem. I am trying send array in multipart formData in swagger 2.0 in laravel. But it is not working. any suggestion? the format is like settings["web_name"], settings["uploaded_file_name"].

Answer (score -1):

Just try it:

```
  *   @SWG\Parameter(
  *       name="game_tournament[]",
  *       type="array",
  *       items="string",
  *       collectionFormat="multi",
  *       required=true,
  *       in="query",
  *   ),
```